# python win32com.client outlook.OpenSharedItem replacing spaces with %20

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, pywin

I am using win32com.client to check an email for attachements, if there is an attachment it populates a wxpython listbox with the attachment file name(s).  It only works if the email name does not contain spaces.  If there are spaces in the file name, it replaces them with a "%20" which results in an error.  I tried using `urllib.unquote()` but that did not work. Can anyone help with this?

```
def onListBox(self, event):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        self.email = event.GetEventObject().GetStringSelection()
        msg2 = outlook.OpenSharedItem(self.emailLocale + self.email)
        att=msg2.Attachments
        print
        if len(att):
            attachList = [i.FileName for i in att]
            self.attachList.Set(attachList)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\onp1ldy\eclipse-workspace\WOrk\EmailParser.py", line 137, in
>   onListBox
>       msg2 = outlook.OpenSharedItem(urllib.unquote(self.emailLocale + self.email).decode('utf8'))   File "", line 2,
>   in OpenSharedItem pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception
>   occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Outlook', u"We can't open
>   'C://Users/onp1ldy/Desktop/emails/emails_sent/Canceled%20%20skype.msg'.
>   It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission
>   to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder,
>   then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)

Comment: OpenSharedItem does not mangle file names. Are you sure "self.email" in your code is not mangled?

Comment: If I `print self.email` if comes out as Canceled  skype.msg with two spaces

Comment: Figured it out, after reading online, realized that `OpenSharedItem()` requires an absolute path.  Using `os.path.abspath()` fixed the issue